CSS size nested DIV based on parent parent DIV size
Say I have this HTML
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    <div id="nested">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

Where

all the DIVs are responsive, in that #outer's width is a percentage of the window width
#inner is "always" smaller than #outer

With CSS, is there a way to set the width of #nested so that it's a percentage of the width of #outer?

I found an answer with CSS container queries
MDN container queries
With this HTML
<body>
  <div id="outer">
    <div id="in">
      <div id="inner">
        <div id="nested">
          <p style="font-size: 2rem;">Hello!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

and this CSS
body {
  background-color: #2C2C2C;
}
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
}
#outer {
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 80%;
  container-type: inline-size;
  container-name: bar;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
#in {
  background-color: rgb(202, 243, 161);
  top: 0;
  bottom: 1px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 20%;
  overflow: visible;
}
#inner {
  background-color: rgb(221, 175, 114);
  top: 0;
  bottom: 1px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 20%;
  overflow: visible;
}
#nested {
  background-color: rgb(37, 231, 167);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 25%;
  height: 75%;
}
@container bar (min-width: 1px) {
  #nested {
    width: 50cqw;
  }
}    

the width of #nested is responsive at 50% of the width of #outer (and not of its immediate parent.) I still need to do a bunch of testing, and to work out the appropriate value to use in @container but I'm well on the way.

You can do so with position: relative and position: absolute
Both these attributes go hand-in-hand as the absolute element is positioned relative to its closest parent/ancestor. It goes up to the body tag if none are found. By setting position: relative on outer, you make it the closest ancestor, so the width of nested adjusts in relation to that.


#outer {
  height: 10rem;
  width: 80vw; /* 80% of the screen width */
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

#inner {
  height: 10rem;
  width: 80%;
  background: gray;
}

#nested {
  height: 10rem;
  width: 50%;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
}
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    <div id="nested">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Yes what you wrote works but (I should've said so) alas #inner has a value for position - so you solution doesn't work for me.

Maybe provide more information in your question or a minimally reproducible example

inner doesn't need a position attribute, or do you mean your outer already has a position?

Apologies for being ambiguous. All the elements have a position property. I want to size #nested with relation to #outer. In this case, I don't care about the width of #inner.

Take advantages of the CSS FlexBox Layout and the flex property and all of its great features. You can read more about flex on this link. Check my example below using the flex value in the display property. Happy Coding!


body {
    background-color: #000738;
}
#outer {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #ef3340;
    height: 240px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 90vh;
}

#inner {
    width: 79%;
    background-color: #04aeec;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  height: 80vh;
}

#nested {
    width: 77%;
    background-color: #88df80;
    height: 60vh;
}
<div id="outer">
   <div id="inner">
      <div id="nested">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>




Hmm, your CSS says that #nested is 77% of #outer but as a percentage of #outer it's around 61%!

Hey there, @AndrewFoulds! Whether it's 77% or 61%, these numbers are just examples. Feel free to adjust them to fit your needs. I included them because your question didn't provide specific information or any code you've worked on yet. Sharing a bit more detail can help us understand your goal better. Thanks, pal!

Sorry I thought my original question was clear. Anyhow, for example if #outer is (as you look at it - it's width is actually a %) 100mm wide. I need #nested to be, say, 50% of that ie. 50mm wide. The sizing is responsive so if #outer's width grows to 120mm then #nested's width will grow to 60mm. All the elements have a position property. Although #nested if within #inner I need to be able to treat #nested's width as though #inner doesn't exist.
